# API for graphics for IBM Bluemix container

Tags: graphics, containers, ibm-cloud

Is is possible to retreive memory/network/cpu stats or graphs from an api for a IBM Bluemix Container?

I know it is possible to show graphics in the IBM Bluemix console. But I want to show the graphics on my own webpage, which runs outside Bluemix.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not heard anything to my question about the api for graphs. Does anyone know this?

Comment: No, it is not currently possible. They have not exposed an API for users.

Answer (score 2):

Monitoring and logging of Bluemix containers is documented at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_ml_ov.html

If you do `cf ic inspect <container>` you will see JSON describing the memory and CPUs available to your containers.